# GNU grub error when i start my system after i edited partitions

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, grub, gnu

I attempted to increase c-drive memory by using a partition tool,earlier i had my system dual boot(window8.1 and ubuntu 15)now after doing the partition using partition tool when i start my computer it shows

GNU GRUB version 2.02^beta2-9ubuntu1

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

please help me solve this problem,how can i get both mu windows and ubuntu back

Answer (score 0):

1.Boot with Ubuntu Live CD or USB.
2.Find your ubuntu partition:
`sudo blkid`

Mine show `/dev/sda1`

`[~] : sudo blkid                                                                                                                                                18:05:04
/dev/sda1: UUID="122d2898-41c4-4d0b-a6e3-efdabacc0910" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b342201c-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="ssd2" UUID="10A1139E10A1139E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="b342201c-02"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="64Win7" UUID="01D25439F551BF10" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="f0b1ebb0-01"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="RELAX" UUID="9626FEB726FE9787" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="f0b1ebb0-02"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="CLGT" UUID="E4481765481735B0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="c887c887-01"
/dev/loop0: UUID="c901eeeb-0431-40dd-bac7-6ced930103b1" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/mapper/docker-8:1-1327350-pool: UUID="c901eeeb-0431-40dd-bac7-6ced930103b1" TYPE="xfs"`


3.Then rebuild your grub config:

`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts 
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
update-grub`


4.Reboot and you can use Ubuntu as normally.